# Play conditional sounds on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, ruby-on-rails, audio

I'm having an interesting problem playing sounds on iPhones/iPads via a rails web app and JavaScript.

One of two sounds should be played depending on the input from a user form. There is no way to determine which sound should be played purely on the client side.

It worked from the start on PC, and after a bit of work I got it working on Android, but I can't seem to get it working on iPads or iPhones and that is what this app was built for.

I'm trying to play a `.wav` file it that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var audio = document.createElement('audio');
        audio.setAttribute('src', 'audio.mp3');
        audio.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
        //audio.load()

        $.get();

        audio.addEventListener("load", function() {
            audio.play();
        }, true);
    });
</script>
```

You can call the audio.play(); function once you are done processing the user input.